# How to bind LINQ data to dropdownlist

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, ado.net

The last two lines of this code do not work correctly -- the results are coming back from the LINQ query.  I'm just not sure how to successfully bind the indicated columns in the results to the textfield and valuefield of the dropdownlist:

```
    protected void BindMarketCodes()
    {
        List<lkpMarketCode> mcodesList = new List<lkpMarketCode>();

        LINQOmniDataContext db = new LINQOmniDataContext();

        var mcodes = from p in db.lkpMarketCodes 
                        orderby 0
                        select p;

        mcodesList = mcodes.ToList<lkpMarketCode>();

        //bind to Country COde droplist
        dd2.DataSource = mcodesList;
        dd2.DataTextField = mcodesList[0].marketName;
        dd2.DataValueField = mcodesList[0].marketCodeID.ToString();

    }
```

Answer (score 29, accepted):

See revised code below

```
protected void BindMarketCodes()
{    
    using (var dataContext = new LINQOmniDataContext()) {
        //bind to Country COde droplist
        dd2.DataSource = from p in dataContext.lkpMarketCodes 
            orderby p.marketName
            select new {p.marketCodeID, p.marketName};
        dd2.DataTextField = "marketName";
        dd2.DataValueField = "marketCodeID";
        dd2.DataBind();
    }
}
```

Comment: couldn't get it work until I added dd2.DataBind(); as suggested by #Andrew_Robinson

Answer (score 33):

```
protected void BindMarketCodes()
{
    using(var dc = new LINQOmniDataContext())
    {
        dd2.DataSource = from p in db.lkpMarketCodes
                         orderby 0
                         select new {p.marketName, p.marketCodeID };
        dd2.DataTextField = "marketName";
        dd2.DataValueField = "marketCodeID";
        dd2.DataBind();
    }
}

// no need to use ToList()
// no need to use a temp list;
// using an anonymous type will limit the columns in your resulting SQL select
// make sure to wrap in a using block;
```

Comment: Thanks for adding this. I like your approach better, for the reasons that you outlined.

Comment: how to add attributes to dd2 in this way?

Comment: How would you reference this in a view?  I am looking for a way to solve this exact issue.

Comment: Mine broke without ToList()

Answer (score -3):

```
DropDownList ddl_RouteLocation = (DropDownList)e.Row.FindControl("ddl_RouteLocation");   

ddl_RouteLocation.DataSource = dtLocation;--(dtlocation i have return method of linq in dtlocation)
ddl_RouteLocation.DataTextField =dtLocation.Rows[0]"LocationName"].ToString();
ddl_RouteLocation.DataValueField =dtLocation.Rows[0]["LocationId"].ToString();
ddl_RouteLocation.DataBind();
ddl_RouteLocation.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("--Select--", "0"));
```

Comment: This solution is too complex and can be realized more easy - see answer by andleer