# Unable to bind LINQ results to drop down

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-5, asp.net-4.5

I am new to link and was following [How to bind LINQ data to dropdownlist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/554649/how-to-bind-linq-data-to-dropdownlist) to try and bind my data to a drop down list using LINQ but I am getting the error "Data binding directly to a store query (DbSet, DbQuery, DbSqlQuery) is not supported. Instead populate a DbSet with data, for example by calling Load on the DbSet, and then bind to local data. For WPF bind to DbSet.Local. For WinForms bind to DbSet.Local.ToBindingList()." I followed the code example so i am not sure what I am doing wrong or how to fix it. Can anyone please adivse as this is day two of using LINQ.

```
            using (var db = new FullContext())
            {
                ddlItemType.DataSource = from t in db.ItemTypes
                                         select new { t.ID, t.Name };
                ddlItemType.DataTextField = "Name";
                ddlItemType.DataValueField = "ID";
                ddlItemType.DataBind();
            }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are `binding dropdown with query instead of data object`. The statement you have return query but not the actual data. You need to bind it with data object for instance list.

Change query

```
ddlItemType.DataSource = from t in db.ItemTypes
     select new { t.ID, t.Name };
```

To data source

```
ddlItemType.DataSource =  (from t in db.ItemTypes
     select new { t.ID, t.Name }).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try:

```
ddlItemType.DataSource = (from t in db.ItemTypes
                          select new { t.ID, t.Name }).ToList()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void ListItem(DropDownList container) {
        DbDataContext db = new DbDataContext();
        var rs = from t in db.ItemTypes
                         select new { t.ID, t.Name };

        foreach (var r in rs)
            container.Items.Add(new ListItem(t.ID + " - " + t.Name, t.ID));
}
```

**to call :**

> ListItem(YourDropdownListID);