# linq to dropdown list in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, .net, linq, web

can someone help me

Im having issues binding my dropdown list from my sql linq query, theres seems to be issues with anon types not being statically typed and then the list is not being populated

please help thanks

```
public static void getlocation()
{
    DataClasses_AbintegroDataContext dc = new DataClasses_AbintegroDataContext("name = name");


    //List<Location> thelocations = new List<Location>(); 

    var locations = new[] { from a in dc.Locations select new { a.name } };


    DropDownList ddLocation = new DropDownList();

    ddLocation.DataSource = locations;
    ddLocation.DataTextField = "Location";
    ddLocation.DataValueField = "Location";


}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/554649/how-to-bind-linq-data-to-dropdownlist

Answer (score 0):

Try this, You have missed `ddLocation.DataBind();` and did't add this dynamic  `DDL` to any Controls  and needs to be some changes

```
public static void getlocation()
{
    DataClasses_AbintegroDataContext dc = new DataClasses_AbintegroDataContext("name = name");
    List<Location> locations =  (from a in dc.Locations).ToList();
    DropDownList ddLocation = new DropDownList();    
    ddLocation.DataSource = locations;
    ddLocation.DataTextField = "name";
    ddLocation.DataValueField = "Id";
    ddLocation.DataBind();
    divRunServer.Controls.Add(ddLocation);

}
```

add this div tag in client side

```
<div id="divRunServer" runat="server"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks, however im now getting " Cannot convert method group 'ToArray' to non-delegate type 'object'. did you intend to invoke a method?, god im having a nightmare day, thanks for your help

Comment: I have updated my answer. Please check it now

Answer (score 0):

**Try it:**

```
public static void getlocation()
{
    DataClasses_AbintegroDataContext dc = new DataClasses_AbintegroDataContext("name = name");
    var locations =  from a in dc.Locations;
    DropDownList ddLocation = new DropDownList();

    ddLocation.DataSource = locations.ToList();
    ddLocation.DataTextField = "name";
    ddLocation.DataValueField = "Id";
    ddLocation.DataBind();
}
```

I hope it will help you.

Comment: Thanks, however im now getting " Cannot convert method group 'ToArray' to non-delegate type 'object'. did you intend to invoke a method?, god im having a nightmare day, thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

Another way:

```
public static void getlocation()
{
    DataClasses_AbintegroDataContext dc = new DataClasses_AbintegroDataContext("name = name"); 
    var locations = from a in dc.Locations select new {a1 = a.Id, a2 = a.name };
    DropDownList ddLocation = new DropDownList();
    ddLocation.DataSource = locations;
    ddLocation.DataValueField = "a1";
    ddLocation.DataTextField = "a2";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Anonymous types should work fine, you just provided property names for `DataTextField` and `DataValueField` that aren't in your anonymous type.  Try:

```
                                                    V-- give the property a name
var locations = from a in dc.Locations select new { Location = a.name };

DropDownList ddLocation = new DropDownList();

ddLocation.DataSource = locations;
ddLocation.DataTextField = "Location";
ddLocation.DataValueField = "Location";
```

However I notice you're not *doing* anything with the `DropDownList` that you create - you may be unintentionally hiding a page control named `ddLocation`.